# Why does light not flood the room?

Tags: visible-light, photons

When I flip on a light and it "floods the room" why is it that photons do not actually *flood the room*, making it brighter and brighter, given the lighting mechanism continues to have an electric current running through it?

My initial thought was that it had to do with the roughly constant temperature of the filament or constant current through the diode producing a constant amount of light which stabilizes the rate of its absorption by objects in the room, other light sources and everything floating around in the air, but this equilibrium seems so tenuous given the apparent stability and constancy of the light. Moreover, even if I removed all the objects from the room except the light, I don't see the brightness being perceivably intensified. Would this not suggest that the walls, floor and ceiling are the greatest contributors to this appearance of constancy?

Any answer/comment would be most appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You may be on the right track if you want to build a LASER.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bodies absorb light. The light gets converted to heat. See the Wikipedia article on [black body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_body):

> A black body or blackbody is an idealized physical body that absorbs all incident electromagnetic radiation, regardless of frequency or angle of incidence.

Blackbodies are idealized things that don't exist in real life, but most real items come close to being black bodies. That's where the light is going - out of the lamp and into the objects in the room. Even if you remove all the objects, the light still goes into the walls. Some light is reflected (which is why we can see them), but some is absorbed, and the situation quickly reaches a steady state where the light produced is balanced by the light absorbed.

Comment: It might help to mention that a room is always connected to the outside world as well, so the steady state is actually the light adding energy and the room radiating energy to the rest of the world.